# c# Convert a generic object to its real object

Tags: c#, variables, dynamic, ssis, casting

I wrote a task script in a SSIS package. I have an object type variable VAR_A and I have assigned a ClassA object to that variable VAR_A.

Like:-

```
ClassA classA=new ClassA();
Dts.Variables["User::VAR_A"].Value = classA; //Assigned here
```

Now I have another task script, where I am getting VAR_A variable as an OBJECT class object but now I wanted to convert this object into ClassA object dynamically or using refection. Because there can be multiple object and I wanted to print all objects value using ToString() which I have overridden in all my classes.

Something Like below:-

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application app = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application();

Package pkg = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\Users\Sample-SSIS-Package\\" + @"sample_Package.dtsx",  null);

Variables pkgVars = pkg.Variables;

foreach (Variable pkgVar in pkgVars)
{
  if (pkgVar.DataType == TypeCode.Object)
  {
    Object obj = pkgVar.Value;  

    //This below line should be dynamic, I cant use manual casting because this can be ClassA or ClassB or CLassC ..anything 

    ClassA ca=(ClassA)obj ; 
    MessageBox.Show(pkgVar.Name+ "-----"+ca.ToString());             

  }
}
```

Comment: As far as `Object` has `ToString` method, you can use `MessageBox.Show(pkgVar.Name+ "-----"+obj.ToString());` and if you want to check that `obj` is `ClassA`, use `if(obj is ClassA) (obj as ClassA).DoSomeThing();`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly.
Is this right: You use several classes that all implement the ToString() method. In your program you don't know from which class your object actually is but you want to call its ToString() method.

In this case you can call the Object.ToString() method in your program.

Example:

```
class Class1
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Class1";
    }
}
 class Class2
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Class2";
        }
    }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cl1 = new Class1();
            var cl2 = new Class2();
            Test(cl1);
            Test(cl2);
        }

        static void Test(Object obj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
```

The obj.ToString() method returns "Class1" in the first call and "Class2" in the second call. If I undestood you right this is the requested behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know all the possible class types you're going to get then you can do something like this:

```
     switch(obj.GetType().Name)
     {
         case "ClassA":
              ClassA ca = obj as ClassA;
              break;
         case "ClassB":
              ClassB cb = obj as ClassB;
              break;
     }
```

If all you want is the name of the class then obj.GetType().Name should do it.